# Angular ng-init not loading

Tags: angularjs

So I'm using ng-init and it is working on one portion of my application, but not the other.

Working Part for ng-init.

html

```
 <input ng-model="sh.editedSchedule._id" class="form-control" type="text" name="" ng-init="sh.editedSchedule._id=sh.scheduleProfile._id" readonly="readonly"></input>
```

controller

```
    scheduleCtrl.scheduleProfile = {};
    scheduleCtrl.editedSchedule = {};

    scheduleCtrl.updateSchedule = (schedule) => {
        console.log('here is scheduleProfile._id: ', 
      scheduleCtrl.scheduleProfile._id);
        schedulesFactory.update(schedule)
                        .then((r) => {
                          console.log('Updated Schedule!', r);
                          scheduleCtrl.saved = true;
                        })
      }
```

Not Working Part for ng-init

html

```
 <input ng-model="cc.editedCourse._id" class="form-control" type="text" name="" ng-init="cc.editedCourse._id=cc.courseProfile._id" readonly="readonly"></input>
  This works, {{cc.courseProfile._id}}
```

controller

```
  courseCtrl.courseProfile = {};
  courseCtrl.editedCourse = {};

         courseCtrl.updateCourse = (course) => {
         console.log('Here is course id: ', courseCtrl.courseProfile._id);
         coursesFactory.update(course)
                       .then((r) => {
                         console.log('course updated: ', r);
                          courseCtrl.saved = true;
                       })
       }
```

So the first part is working great and the ng-init is loading, setting sh.editedSchedule._id=sh.scheduleProfile._id. When I try to do the same thing with the second part, the ng-init is not executing??

Comment: Are you sure that it is not executed? Or maybe `cc.courseProfile._id` is not assigned before the `ng-init` is trying to use it?

Comment: Yeah it is not executed, I updated the answer that shows Angular displaying `cc.courseProfile._id`.

Comment: Could be a timing issue. 
In your code you're setting `courseCtrl.editedCourse = {};`. Maybe that get's executed after the ng-init. 
Try putting a console.log inside the ng-init and one where you set it to `{}`in your controller and see in what order they are executed.

Comment: That what I was thinking. Also, as the documentation for `ngInit` says, you probably should assign these values in controller.

Comment: I figured out a workaround I'll post answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so I had to utilize $broadcast to initialize a function, still could use some tweaks. So in the not working part here is what I did.

html - I removed the ng-init and just fired it off below

```
 <input ng-model="cc.editedCourse._id" class="form-control" type="text" name="" readonly="readonly"></input>
  {{ init() }}
```

controller - I set up a $broadcast to change what I had to, it works the way I want it to now. Open to any suggestions.

```
       $scope.init = () => {
          console.log('fired  init...')
          $rootScope.$broadcast('modelchange-started');
       }

       $scope.$on('modelchange-started', () => {
         console.log('fired  In modelchange-started...')
          courseCtrl.editedCourse._id = courseCtrl.courseProfile._id
          return courseCtrl.editedCourse._id
       })
```